# how to manually set the fetch origin for git repo?

Tags: git, github

I know I can add several remotes for a git repo so that a push goes to several repos with this command

```
git remote set-url --add --push origin https://user@bitbucket.org/group/repo.git
```

But what would be the equivalent command for manually changing the remote to fetch from? I tried

```
git remote set-url --add --fetch origin https://user@bitbucket.org/group/repo.git
```

But that didn't work, and in the manpage that displays, there seems to be no option for a fetch, so I guess it's done in a different way entirely?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `--fetch` because a single URL is used for both push *and* fetch, unless there is a specific push URL.  `--set-url` sets this "main" or "default" or "regular" URL.  (There's no particularly good adjective for it, it's just "the URL" as opposed to "the push-URL".)

Note that using `--add` tells `git remote set-url` to add a *new* URL; if you want to change an existing URL, leave out `--add` so that it removes the old one.

This may all make more sense if you "peek under the covers": run `git config --edit` (and then just view it and exit your editor) or `cat .git/config` to see what's in the config file.  You will find a section for each remote that looks something like this:

```
[remote "origin"]
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
    url = ...
```

If there is a separate push URL there will be one more line in the section:

```
    pushurl = ...
```

Note that you can create and edit these lines with your editor (`git config -e`) instead of the command-line tools, it's just that if you do that, you are responsible for getting everything right (e.g., syntax nits).  (I use this edit mode to fix things or conduct various experiments with git, sometimes.)